# how to use a sprite as an anchor point of another sprite?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, 2d, sprite

I want to know , if you can , join two sprites in libgdx .

Let me explain, I have a spaceship that I have to turn in my game ... and is the first sprite .

another sprite I would put on the tip of the spacecraft so that when it turns me I through the second sprite I can always know the coordinates and so derive a vector in order to advance my ship .

I'm new to libgdx and if anyone had any idea would be grateful.

Thank You.

**EDIT**
: I would follow that always render the position of the other sprites , currently does not happen , tips ? Thank You.

```
@Override
public void render () {

    sprite.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - sprite.getWidth()/2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - sprite.getHeight()/2);
    point.setPosition(sprite.getX() + (sprite.getWidth()/2 - point.getWidth()/2), sprite.getY() + (sprite.getHeight() / 2 + point.getHeight()));

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    if(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Buttons.LEFT)){
        //sprite.setPosition(Gdx.input.getX() - sprite.getWidth()/2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.input.getY() - sprite.getHeight()/2);
        if(Gdx.input.getX() < Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2)
        {
            //System.out.println("x: " + Gdx.input.getX() + " - y: " + Gdx.input.getY());
            sprite.setRotation(rotation++);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("x: " + Gdx.input.getX() + " - y: " + Gdx.input.getY());
            sprite.setRotation(rotation--);
            point.setRotation(rotation--);
        }
    }

    batch.begin();
    spacesprite.draw(batch);
    sprite.draw(batch);
    point.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}
```

**EDIT 2**

[image: Space Ship]

As you can see in the picture , I would like that when I rotate the sprite of the spacecraft , the red dot ( which is another sprite ) remain on the tip of the spacecraft . So you can calculate a vector with the points of origin of the two sprites .

I hope to have been clear .
A union of two sprites is not possible in libgdx else?

**EDIT 3**

[image: Red Dot is not follow spaceship]

picture , I wish that when the ship rotates the red ball remains always on the tip of the spacecraft . is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If your two sprite have the same width can use this:

this is psudo code mor or less.

```
float pointY = yourSprite.getY() + yourSprite.getHeight();
float pointX = yourSprite.getX(); 

yourOtherSprite. setX(pointX);
yourOtherSprite. setY(pointY);
```

if diferente width

```
float pointY = yourSprite.getY() + yourSprite.getHeight();
float pointX = yourSprite.getX() + (yourSprite.getWidth() / 2); 

yourOtherSprite. setX(pointX - (thisSprite.getWidth() / 2));
yourOtherSprite. setY(pointY);
```

I can not test now, but so you have an idea.

**New**

I do not know if is this what you mean if not so comment it and delete:

P.s: points* is a Vector2:

```
pointSpriteA.x = yourSprite.getX() + (yourSprite.getHeight() / 2);
pointSpriteB.x = yourOtherSprite.getY() + (yourOtherSprite.getHeight() / 2);

pointSpriteA.y = yourSprite.getY() + (yourSprite.getWidth() / 2);
pointSpriteB.y = yourOtherSprite.getY() + (yourOtherSprite.getWidth() / 2);

pointC.X = (pointSpriteA.x + pointSpriteB.x) / 2);
pointC.y = (pointSpriteA.Y + pointSpriteB.y) / 2);
```

the pointC vector is the center of the two vectors.

if that's what you want, and ask yourself, how to rotate? sprites can this helps.

[LibGDX - Rotate a 2d array of sprites around their center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555023/libgdx-rotate-a-2d-array-of-sprites-around-their-center/27555676#27555676)

Comment: I edited the question , so as to better understand what I need, it is important that you always follow the render . so you can calculate a vector from the center of the two sprites .
thank you.

Comment: maybe I explained badly, with the image I uploaded is easier to understand my problem ? Thank You

Comment: @Alex perhaps the link, I put, you can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555023/libgdx-rotate-a-2d-array-of-sprites-around-their-center/27555676#27555676

Comment: helps me in part , I wish that the red dot was always at the top of the image of the spacecraft .
The position of the septum without problems , is when I click in the render () that the red ball does not follow the tip of the spacecraft , latest tips ? Thank You

Comment: @Alex is costing me understand you, you express is not bad, if my English is not very good, but if you have the pivot point, you just have to apply the rotation to each sprite, if I understand you want to do i think

Comment: I applied the rotation of each sprite ... but the rotation is about himself , and not with the spacecraft .
however I do not want you to miss any more time , you have been very patient , I see if I find something online .

Comment: I edited one more time , it's clear what I want to do? thanks

Comment: @Alex if what I understand, depends on how the spacecraft is rotated, but you could make something like that I think, you define one vector inside the ship to be the vector which rotate the ball,"use the link for aplicar to sprite vector point" when you rotate the spacecraft, take the get angle rotation, and draw the ball and the rotation you give the ball is the ship, not what I mean, do you rotate the ball around the ship, but as this also rotates the ball stays in the same place with respect to ship

Comment: @Alex P.S: I think this may help you if not now in the future  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27671908/rotate-texture-in-

Comment: I would say that I have recommended the right way , now I see how you do carriers , is all new to me. Thank you very much.

If you edit the question by saying to a vector that rotates the sign as you correctly , just for people like me , you enter on a new landscape as libgdx .

Thank You