# LibGDX Rotating a sprite at each iteration

Tags: rotation, libgdx, sprite

I'm using the function

```
SpriteBatch.draw(region, x, y, originX, originY, width, height, scaleX, scaleY, rotation);
```

And I call it as, being `screen` a `SpriteBatch` and `img` as `Sprite`, the variable `dir` is in radians:

```
screen.draw(img, x, y, 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), 0.8f, 0.8f, dir*180/((float) Math.PI));
```

What I'm getting is a rotation around a pivot and not the center of the image nor the coordinates x,y which holds that said center.

I have already tried to use the sprite functions, centerOrigin and setCenter and neither of them changes to what I Want.

Comment: not know if this can help you, it is a response some time ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27906517/how-to-use-a-sprite-as-an-anchor-point-of-another-sprite/27908723#27908723 or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555023/libgdx-rotate-a-2d-array-of-sprites-around-their-center/27555676#27555676

Answer (score 0):

Set all the scaling and position and rotation on the sprite `img` and then call `img.draw(spriteBatch);` instead of `spriteBatch.draw(...)`. The `spriteBatch.draw(...)` method that you are calling is not aware of any parameters that you set on the sprite, such as calling `setCenter` on it, so you have to draw it from the sprite.

Answer (score 0):

The X and Y co-ordinates which represent the centre of the object should be given as originX and originY if you want the image to rotate around its centre.

```
screen.draw(img, x, y, img.getWidth() / 2, img.getHeight() / 2, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), 0.8f, 0.8f, dir*180/((float) Math.PI));
```